# Find cheapest cycle in an undirected weighted graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, cycle

I'm stuck on searching an algorithm to find the cheapest cycle in a weighted undirected graph in O(n^2). The cycle does not have to visit every vertex in the graph (i.e. I'm not looking for a Hamiltonian cycle).

Can someone help me finding a strategy?

an example of weighted undirected graph:

[image]

Comment: Considering the list of all cycles may be longer than O(n^2), the answer is no, we can't help you do that.

Comment: Your example output is missing cycles. Can you give a precise description of what you want to achieve, or fix your example output if you got the description right the first time?

Comment: this problem would help me in finding the cheapest tour in weighted graph. A tour is a loop in the cycle, so I have to traverse all nodes to find all cycles and output the one with the minimum weight.

Comment: @user2357112 I updated the outputs, can you understand it now?

Comment: If you want to find the cheapest cycle, that's much, much easier than finding all of them. If you want to find the cheapest [*Hamiltonian*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) cycle, you're still out of luck.

Comment: @user2357112 My goal is to find the cheapest cycle.. not necessarily a cycle has to touch each vertex.

Comment: http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~itai/publications/Algorithms/min-circuit.pdf and http://research.haifa.ac.il/~raphy/papers/all-cycles.pdf may help, though they're pretty technical.

Comment: @user2357112 So doesn't exists a O(n^2) solution? Can you explain me better, since even reading your link I can't figure it out.

Comment: I'd be surprised if anyone found a quadratic-time algorithm. Even in the unweighted case, my search didn't turn up anything that fast.

Comment: Does your graph have some special properties such as being planar? If so, this is actually quite easy.

Comment: does the cycle have to be simple or can it visit an intermediate node multiple times? Also, what about 2-cycles? As in A -> B -> A? Also, can you have negative edge weights?

Comment: No it hasn't to be necessarily planar, and a cycle has to be simple, no negative weights

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure where the O(n^2) time bound came from. The obvious O(n (m + n log n))-time algorithm is, for each vertex, to compute a shortest-path tree from that vertex and then consider the fundamental cycle made by a non-tree edge and some tree edges.

Comment: Good one, this will work, but there's probably a time savings that can be found somewhere ...

Comment: You can terminate the shortest path tree construction as soon as in your shortest path tree construction algorithm you visit a visited node already. This forms the cheapest cycle for this vertex. It will improve average case runtime but worst case runtime remains unchanged.